# Buttons getting enabled when running BackgroundWorker Win2K8

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm facing strange issue, where in the buttons are getting enabled when I run my C# Windows program on a VM configured for Win2K8.

My dev PC is Windows 7. The program basically spawns a backgroundworker thread to perform some long running operation when the user clicks the play button.

Just before I start my BackgroundWorker thread using RunWorkerAsync call, I enable and disable some buttons on my UI.

```
btnBuild.Enabled = false;
btnStop.Enabled = true;
backWorkerScript.RunWorkerAsync(m_oArgs);
```

When I test on my dev PC(Windows 7), the behaviour is as expected i.e, the button state is what I expect it to be.

But When I deploy the same WindowsApplication.exe, the button **btnBuild gets enabled**

Attached is the screengrab for reference [image: app comparison]

The left image - Application run on Windows 2008, 
The right image - Application run on Windows 7,

Nowhere I'm trying to access UI threads from different threads.

I'm enabling the button only in the RunWorkerCompleted event handled in the OnExecuteComplete event handler

```
private void OnExecuteComplete(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                toolStripStatus.Text = "Task Cancelled.";
            }
                // Check to see if an error occurred in the background process.
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                toolStripStatus.Text = "Error";
           }
            else
            {
                //Final Status
                toolStripStatus.Text = "Operation completed successfully.";
            }

            //Change the status of the buttons on the UI accordingly
            btnBuild.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  Like the code where the button *should* actually be re-enabled after the worker finishes?

Comment: @roryap : I have included